# Python - I cannot get a comma to write to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a program that takes a sentence that has been inputted, puts it in a dictionary with the position of each word and punctuation and then the sentence is recreated exactly like the original but i cannot get the program to put a comma into the dictionary with a position. It does however work with all other punctuation. This is my code please help!

```
def calPositions():
import json #imports the json module
import re #imports the regular expression module
from collections import defaultdict #imports a dictionary

punctuation = r"[ {},:'[\]1-5]+"  

d = defaultdict(list) #creates the dictionary and assigns it too the variable d

sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ") #Asks the user to input a sentence

for position, word in enumerate(re.split(punctuation, sentence), start=1):# goes through each word one by one
    d[word].append(position) #gives each word in the sentence a position

print ("your sentence was: " ,sentence) #displays the sentence the user entered
print ("The sentence with their positions of the words is: ",d) #displays the position of the words

json.dump(d, open("original.txt",'w')) #puts the dictionary in the file

menu() #sends the user back to the menu

def recreate():

import json

d = json.load(open("original.txt")) #opens the text file so it can be read
print (d) #displays the dictionary

position = 1 #creates the variable position 
sentence2 = []

while position:
    for word, positions in d.items():# this uses the positions of the words 
        if position in positions:    # to put the words in the correct order
            sentence2.append(word)   # so the recreated sentence can be displayed
            position += 1
            break 
    else:
        position = 0

print(' '.join(sentence2))#prints the recreated sentence 

menu()


def menu():
correct = "false"
while correct == "false":
    print("""
             Welcome to the program. Please choose an option.""")#displays the options for the user
    choice =input("""
             Option 1 Input sentence to calculate positions - calculate
             Option 2 Recreate orginal sentence - recreate
             Option 3 End - end : """)

    if choice == "calculate":
        correct = "true"
        calPositions() # if the user chooses calculate it runs the function calPositions
    elif choice == "recreate":
        correct = "true"
        recreate() # if the user chooses recreate it runs the function recreate
    elif choice == "end":
        correct = "true"
        return # if the user chooses end the program ends
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid option.")#if the user inputs anything else it asks them to enter a valid option
```

menu()

Comment: can you show us the input/output/expected output?

Comment: please fix issues with indentation and share input/output.

Comment: It does work with duplicate words as it gives them a position of both positions they occur in the sentence the only thing that does not work with this code is inputting a sentence with a comma and the program not putting the comma into the dictionary with a position

Comment: Option 1 Input sentence to calculate positions - calculate
Option 2 Recreate orginal sentence - recreate
Option 3 End - end : calculate
Please enter a sentence: my name is finn!
your sentence was:  my name is finn!
The sentence with their positions of the words is:  defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'finn!': [4], 'is': [3], 'name': [2], 'my': [1]})
Option 1 Input sentence to calculate positions - calculate
Option 2 Recreate orginal sentence - recreate Option 3 End - end : recreate
{'name': [2], 'is': [3], 'finn!': [4], 'my': [1]}
my name is finn!  @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use the comma as separator here: `punctuation = r"[ {},:'[\]1-5]+"`  , he will not appears in your dictionary because he will not be returned as a word by the `re.split(punctuation, sentence)`.

You have to find another way to split your word if you want `','` to appears as a word in your sentence.

For example you could use a regex instead of a `re.split` for isolate the different words and punctuation in your sentence.

Edit: A good way to do that is to use `findall`. The best I can find is :

```
re.findall(r"\w+|[^\w ]+", "foo, bar and foo; again!")
['foo', ',', 'bar', 'and', 'foo', ';', 'again', '!']
```

It will find all the word (alphanumeric, with `\w+`) and all the punctuations sign (non alphanumeric without space, with `[^\w ]+`).